# Sorting Flickr photostream

Tags: photos, flickr, photo-sharing

I have been using this great tool (http://sortmyphotostream.michael.tyson.id.au/) to sort my Flickr photostream by the date of the photo rather than the date uploaded. It seems to have disappeared recently. Are there other tools available that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an app that claims to do this (I haven't tested it myself):

Flickr photostream update - A cool app to sort your photos by taken date instead of upload date

http://flickrstream.webzardry.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I remember now seeing that app when I first searched for a solution last year and found Michael Tyson's app. It isn't quite as good because it won't sort photos created before the Flickr account was create (less of a problem for me now) and only does 100 at a time (more of a problem for me now). It is a good alternative though and got the job done, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'd also noticed the web page was down, so left a message on Michael's blog last night and he's fixed the DNS issue that was causing his SortMyPhotostream page to be unavailable.

If you try it again now hopefully you'll have access again.  See last few comments on his blog post.

http://atastypixel.com/blog/sort-your-flickr-photostream/